# Formation of symmetrical ether or dehydration of primary alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My textbook gives the formation of diethyl ether from dehydration of ethyl alcohol:

> $\ce{\underset{\text{ethyl alcohol}}{2C2H5-OH} ->[\text{conc.} H2SO4][413~K] \underset{\text{diethyl ether}}{C2H5-O-C2H5} + H2O}$

In the reaction where it is said that concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ at temperature $413~\mathrm K$ is used as a catalyst, will the primary alcohol not dehydrate to form alkene?

Concentrated sulfuric acid is a strong dehydrating agent, and is used as $95~\%$ concentrated when dehydrating primary alcohol. So will the alcohol dehydrate or will the diethyl ether be formed?

Comment: When forming an alkene this way you have a carbocation intermediate.  This isn't very stable on a terminal carbon, so that pathway is not very favorable.

Comment: Still, if we push harder, it will dehydrate.

Comment: Indeed, $413~\mathrm K$ ($140~^\circ \mathrm C$) is used for this reaction while $453~\mathrm K$ ($180~^\circ \mathrm C$) is used for making ethene from ethanol. We might have to resort to the concept of [thermodynamic and kinetic control](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/59965/34388).

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41836/reactions-of-alcohol-with-sulfuric-acid