# Dehydration: Methylcycloexanol + H2SO4 + THF

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I came across this exercise:

[image: reaction](http://imgur.com/0nli3ZZ)![react]

> Why do we need THF?
>
> How the THF influence the mechanism?

I couldn't find any link or external explanation, if you do please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a solvent. You need to keep the reagents in an environment that's good for reacting,

Comment: That's it? 
So we would still have methylene cyclohexane as a product like we would find in a normal dehydration?

Comment: You won't get methylene cyclohexane, you get 1-methylcyclohexene as mentioned in the picture. But THF doesn't do anything other than that. The solvent was mentioned just so that the reaction is more "descriptive".

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41836/reactions-of-alcohol-with-sulfuric-acid