# What would be the correct mechanism for hydration of ethene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: Mechanism of ethene hydration]

Given above is the mechanism that I drew but my textbook puts it a bit differently. It says that the ethene is dissovled in the concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ to form ethyl hydrogen sulphate $\ce{CH3-CH2OSO3H}$ which when diluted with water reacts to form ethanol and the acid
$$\ce{CH3CH2OSO3H + H-OH -> CH3CH2OH + H2SO4}$$
So which mechanism is true?

Comment: I think that the first mechanism occurs when a solution of sulphuric acid in water is reacted with ethene. The second mechanism occurs if you first add conc. H2SO4 to ethene, and then add water. I am not fully sure, though. I will answer if I get a reference to back my claim.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought your mechanism was very comprehensive but upon closer inspection I think it has some flaws because in this reaction conc. sulphuric acid is used as a catalyst and it must be regenerated at the end and in the above mechanism only ethanol is generated.

[image: mechanism of H2SO4 addition]

This must be the mechanism shown in your book.

Comment: Hmm, yes but no but yes but no …

Comment: The sulphuric acid is indeed regenerated in the proposed mechanism, no?